# How do I make my SOQL results into a URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

How would I make the results of my SOQL table look like this? Essentially having a hyperlink to the service case object so that you can see what is inside the service case.
[image]

Above is the home page of my custom object service cases.

Currently my SOQL results creates a table like this.
[image]

How do I make it so that my SOQL results will also have a link to the service case itself?

Here is my code:

```
<apex:page controller="TestDisplayQueryList"> 
<apex:pageBlock title="My Content"> 
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="Record"> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Name}"/> 
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Id Name</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Id}"/> 
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

That is the vf page and here is the control

```
public with sharing class TestDisplayQueryList{ 
List<Service_case__c> SC = [SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, LastModifiedById, 
                       LastModifiedDate 
                       FROM Service_case__c];
public List<Service_case__c> Records {get; set;}  
public TestDisplayQueryList(){ 
Records = 
[select Name,Id FROM Service_case__c]; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use as like:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!Record.Id}" id="theLink">{!Record.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query already has the data you need. You just need to modify your markup. The markup you need to make a linked name is simply:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Service_Case__c.View, record.Id)}">
    {!record.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```